# Datatable with fixed header and fixed columns using datatable.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I need a [datatable](https://datatables.net/) enabled table that has

1. fixed header / footer with scrolling using the main browser scroll bars
2. left and right columns should be fixed.

DataTables provides 2 plugins [fixedHeader](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader) & [fixedColumns](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns) that provides these features. I am unable to make the two plugins to work together. I am facing following issues:

1. When the header or footer gets fixed, it’s width extends beyond the table width
2. Horizontal scrollbar does not appear when the footer is fixed
3. I have a dropdown menu on the right most column. The menu gets partially hidden

I have provided a sample of my code at [`here`](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/20896/)

Please help me to resolve the issues

Comment: Do your homework by your own :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody').scroll(function(e) { 
    $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the thead relative to the body scrolling
    $('thead th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first cell of the header
    $('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first column of tdbody
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


/*thead*/
thead {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 700px;
  overflow: visible;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #99a;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

thead th:nth-child(1) {/*first cell in the header*/
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #88b;
}


/*tbody*/
tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 700px;
  height: 239px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

tbody td {
  background-color: #bbc;
  min-width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {  /*the first cell in each tr*/
  position: relative;
  display: block; 
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #99a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Town</th>
        <th>County</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Profession</th>
        <th>Anual Income</th>
        <th>Matital Status</th>
        <th>Children</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Smith</td>
        <td>Macelsfield</td>
        <td>Cheshire</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>Brewer</td>
        <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenny Jones</td>
        <td>Threlkeld</td>
        <td>Cumbria</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Shepherdess</td>
        <td>£28,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Peter Frampton</td>
        <td>Avebury</td>
        <td>Wiltshire</td>
        <td>57</td>
        <td>Musician</td>
        <td>£124,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Simon King</td>
        <td>Malvern</td>
        <td>Worchestershire</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>Naturalist</td>
        <td>£65,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lucy Diamond</td>
        <td>St Albans</td>
        <td>Hertfordshire</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>Pharmasist</td>
        <td>Retired</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Austin Stevenson</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>Lothian </td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>Vigilante</td>
        <td>£86,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wilma Rubble</td>
        <td>Bedford</td>
        <td>Bedfordshire</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>Housewife</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kat Dibble</td>
        <td>Manhattan</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>Policewoman</td>
        <td>$36,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Henry Bolingbroke</td>
        <td>Bolingbroke</td>
        <td>Lincolnshire</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>Landowner</td>
        <td>Lots</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alan Brisingamen</td>
        <td>Alderley</td>
        <td>Cheshire</td>
        <td>352</td>
        <td>Arcanist</td>
        <td>A pile of gems</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need a datatable enabled table that doesn't have scrollbar for table scrollbar should be for Document